# g++ question about endianism that *should* work?

Tags: c++, c, endianness, unions, bit-fields

I *thought* this should work, but I'm obviously wrong, but I don't know why :-)
Assume I had the following bytes from the network 0x03 0x02.  In my head, I expect it to be converted to little endian and the following union

```
struct decoded {
    uint16_t opcode : 12;
    uint8_t  unused : 1;
    uint8_t  numRegs : 3;
}

union words {
     decoded a;
     uint8_t byes[2];
}
```

I would expect that I could to a be16toh(a.opcode) and get 0x030 and numRegisters is 0x02.  I find, even with endian conversion, I get things like 0x302 and 0x00, but I have no idea why :-(

Comment: Pray tell, do you have code that shows how you are employing the struct and union? If so, please include your [Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you running on a little- or big-endian CPU?

What is `sizeof(decoded)`?

Comment: It is *extremely* unsafe to assume much of anything about bit fields.  The language spec places considerably fewer requirements on them than people tend to suppose.  The appropriate ABI should fill in all the missing details for a given machine, but that's already saying "not portable".

Comment: Bitfields in the two different types `uint16_t` and `uint8_t` do not share the same same storage. The `uint8_t` types would have to be `uint16_t`. In the `union` your `decoded` struct will take more than the 2 bytes specified in its array member.

Comment: What CPU architecture and compiler version do you have? What code and compiler flags can we use to have a testable example?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field says: "The following properties of bit fields are implementation-defined: [...]
- Whether a bit field can straddle an allocation unit boundary
- The order of bit fields within an allocation unit (on some platforms, bit fields are packed left-to-right, on others right-to-left)"

Comment: Among the things that cppreference does not say but perhaps should: the size of the addressible storage unit to which a bit field is assigned is unspecified.  In particular, the language spec does not tie it in any way to the bitfield's declared type, though some ABIs may do.

Comment: The best way to handle this is to not use bitfields at all. If you have a `uint16_t` in network byte order, convert it to host byte order using `ntohs()` or equivalent, and then use bit-shift and bit-mask operators to extract the values you need.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on my comment, people tend to make a lot of assumptions about structure layout in general and about bitfield layout in particular that simply are not founded on the C or C++ language specification.  The details should be described in the the applicable Application Binary Interface (ABI) specification, but this varies from architecture to architecture and from OS to OS.

All that you can rely upon in general is that

- bitfields will be stored in "pure binary notation"
- storage for bitfields will be assigned within "addressable storage units" chosen by the C or C++ implementation, whose size and alignment requirement is unspecified.
- each ASU will contain at least one bitfield in full
- if there is sufficient space in the chosen ASU then adjacent full bitfields will be packed into adjacent bits of the same one.

It is implementation-defined whether bitfields will span two ASUs in the event that there is some space available at the end of one, but not enough to accommodate the next bitfield.

It is unspecified in what order bitfields will appear within a given ASU.

There are other unspecified and implementation defined aspects of bitfields, too.

But let's consider a program exploring your particular bitfields.  In light of the question being tagged both C and C++, this is written in C++, but in largely C-like idiom:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

struct decoded {
    uint16_t opcode : 12;
    uint8_t  unused : 1;
    uint8_t  numRegs : 3;
};

union words {
    decoded a;
    uint8_t byes[2];
};

int main(void) {
    words u;
    u.byes[0] = 0x03;
    u.byes[1] = 0x02;

    printf("structure size: %zu\n", sizeof(decoded));
    printf("opcode: %#06hx;  unused: %#04hhx;  numRegs: %#04hhx\n", u.a.opcode, u.a.unused, u.a.numRegs);
}
```

On my x86-64 Linux workstation, its output is:

```
structure size: 2
opcode: 0x0203;  unused: 0000;  numRegs: 0000
```

This shows the following about my system:

- the compiler chose a single 16-bit ASU for the structure.  It can't be smaller because it must accommodate a 12-bit bitfield and be a multiple of the size of a `char` (8 bits on this machine).  It is not larger because the size of the whole structure is 16 bits.
- the compiler assigned the `opcode` member to the least-significant 12 bits (0 - 11)
- we can conclude that the compiler assigned `unused` to bit 12, and `numRegs` to bits 13 - 15.

So here's the layout, in storage order:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
L----------- words -----------|
L---------- decoded ----------|
L------------ ASU ------------|
L-- bytes[0] --|--- bytes[1] -|
L----|-|------- opcode -------|
   \   \
    \   +- unused
     +- numRegs
```

It should be clear why the `unused` and `numRegs` fields are both 0.

The bits of the `opcode` are `001100000010`, so the question arises of how to interpret that?  The answer is that the bit pattern is padded with zeroes *on the left* to widen it to the number of bits of a `uint16_t` (since that's the declared type of the bitfield), and interpret it in the ordinary (for this machine) way from there.  Since the machine is little-endian, that gives the reported 0x0203.

> I would expect that I could to a be16toh(a.opcode) and get 0x030 and numRegisters is 0x02.

That would be a plausible result on a machine were bitfields were laid out from left (most-significant) to right.  Mine is not such a machine, and I guess yours isn't either.